# How to implicitly differentiate a curve and get a particular differential equation out of it?

Tags: calculus

> If $2x=y^\frac{1}{5}+y^\frac{-1}{5}$ then $(x^2-1)\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d}x^2}+x\frac{dy}{dx}=ky$, then find the value of 'k'

I was trying to solve this question and kept getting stuck and was never able to create the required differential equation.

My attempt:

Differentiating $2x=y^\frac{1}{5}+y^\frac{-1}{5}$, we get,

$2=\frac{1}{5}\frac{dy}{dx}(y^\frac{-4}{5}-y^\frac{-6}{5})=\frac{1}{5y}\frac{dy}{dx}(y^\frac{1}{5}-y^\frac{-1}{5})$

I can sense some sort of symmetry in this equation but I really don't know how to proceed from here. Differentiating once more creates a bigger mess that I can't seem to manipulate to get to the desired differential equation.

Comment: The hint is for the second part only

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici It's a beautiful solution, thanks a lot for it. Though to find the value of 'k' I had to plug the values from the graph of the curve which I constructed using desmos. I was hoping if there was a way where I don't need to use the graph.

Comment: You don't need anything : compute $x'$ and $x''$ . Replace and simplify. Simple

Comment: Done. Thanks for the push and your patience with me!

Comment: You should have $\frac1y$ not $y$ on your last line. See my answer.

Comment: @DavidQuinn Absolutely! Actually, I did write $\frac{1}{y}$ in the notebook but typed it wrong in MathJax. I'll edit it. Sorry I am new here. Also, your answer actually clarified the piece of the puzzle I was missing. I wasn't able to determine the value of $y^\frac{1}{5}-y^\frac{-1}{5}$ in terms of x. That's crucial to the simplification. I feel dumb after reading the solutions. Thanks a lot for the solution!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

$$(x^2-1)y''+xy'=ky$$ If you switch variables
$$-(x^2-1)\frac {x''}{[x']^3}+\frac{x}{x'}=ky$$ Now, make $x=\frac 12 \left(y^\frac{1}{5}+y^\frac{-1}{5}\right)$ and replace.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a direct method to get $k$:

$$2x=y^{\frac15}+y^{-\frac15}\implies 2=\frac{1}{5y}y’\left(y^{\frac15}-y^{-\frac15}\right)$$

Meanwhile, $$x^2-1=\frac14\left(y^{\frac15}-y^{-\frac15}\right)^2$$

Combining these results by eliminating the bracketed term gives $$\left(y’\right)^2(x^2-1)=25y^2$$

Differentiating this and cancelling the extra $y’$ term leads to the required result $$y’’(x^2-1)+xy’=25y$$

So $k=25$.

Answer (score 1):

Start with your equality and take the derivative respect to x from both, mantain the equality (not the partial derivative).

$$ 2x=y^{\frac{1}{5}}+y^{-\frac{1}{5}} \\ \frac{d}{dx}2x=\frac{d}{dx}(y^{\frac{1}{5}}+y^{-\frac{1}{5}}) = \frac{d}{dx}y^{\frac{1}{5}}+ \frac{d}{dx}y^{-\frac{1}{5}}$$

Since you are differentiating with respect to x, you will consider y a function of x ($y(x)$), and therefore if you don't understand something at some point, you can always break it up and solve it using the chain rule.

$$\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{du}{dv}\cdot \frac{dv}{dx} \ \ \text{or} \ \ \frac{d}{dx}(f(g(x))) = f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$$

Now applying this to each element of the equality and puting it together

$$\frac{d}{dx}(2x) = 2 \\ \frac{d}{dx}(y^{\frac{1}{5}}) = \frac{d}{dx}((y(x))^{\frac{1}{5}}) = \frac{1}{5}\cdot ((y(x))^{\frac{1}{5}-1})\cdot y'(x) = \frac{1}{5}\cdot y^{-\frac{4}{5}}\cdot \frac{dy}{dx} \\ \frac{d}{dx}(y^{-\frac{1}{5}}) = \frac{d}{dx}((y(x))^{-\frac{1}{5}}) = -\frac{1}{5}\cdot ((y(x))^{-\frac{1}{5}-1})\cdot y'(x) = -\frac{1}{5}\cdot y^{-\frac{6}{5}}\cdot \frac{dy}{dx}$$

Now that we have differentiated all the elements in their own (for ease), we can now set them back in the equality, and factor out $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

$$2 = \frac{1}{5}y^{-\frac{4}{5}}\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{1}{5}y^{-\frac{6}{5}}\frac{dy}{dx} \\ 2 = \frac{dy}{dx}( \frac{1}{5}y^{-\frac{4}{5}}-\frac{1}{5}y^{-\frac{6}{5}})$$

You can assume here we could get an expression for $\frac{dy}{dx}$, and that is exactly correct. We will get however an expression in terms of $x$ AND $y$. This might seem strange at first, but it might be helpful to think of it as a scalar field, which asigns some "rate of change" of the value of the field at every point in the plane. This is not rigurous however, it is just an analogy to understand better the problem.

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2}{ \frac{1}{5}y^{-\frac{4}{5}}-\frac{1}{5}y^{-\frac{6}{5}}}$$

As a note, we can factor out the $\frac{1}{5}$ in the bottom and make it cleaner.

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2}{ \frac{1}{5}(y^{-\frac{4}{5}}-y^{-\frac{6}{5}})}=\frac{10}{ y^{-\frac{4}{5}}-y^{-\frac{6}{5}}}$$

This is the final expression. In this particular problem, $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is expressed just in terms of $y$, but do keep in mind it will not always be this way. Note that $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is NOT an equation, it is just an expression, therefore you can not just graph a curve of it, as it covers the whole plane (all you could do is draw some sort of scalar field). Finally, if you want to find all the points in your curve that have a gradient of say $k$, you can create an equation here, by setting $\frac{dy}{dx} = k$. As you will see, this will give you the equation of a new curve, this curve represents all the points in the plane where the derivative equates $k$. As you will see, the mayority of these points are actually not in your original curve, therefore, they will probably not be useful to you. You can think of these curves as "contour lines" like the lines indicating height in maps, they are ALL the points where the "gradient" of your curve is $k$. As you may have guessed, if you want to find the points with gradient $k$ that are in your curve, you can create a simple simultaneous equation system and solve it.

$$\begin{cases} \frac{10}{ y^{-\frac{4}{5}}-y^{-\frac{6}{5}}} = k \\ 2x=y^{\frac{1}{5}}+y^{-\frac{1}{5}} \end{cases}$$

Or more generally

$$ \begin{cases} \frac{dy}{dx} = k \\ \text{your original expression} \end{cases}$$

After solving for x and y, you will get all the points with this gradient (if any). If you want to do the inverse operation and find the gradient at point $(x, y)$, you can just substitute these values into $\frac{dy}{dx}$.